# How do I get an app description based on the gsuite appID

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-apps, google-workspace

**Background;**
As a Gsuite admin it is possible to [review 3rd party app access](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227?hl=en) that the staff in your organisation are using. This returns an on-screen report that provides the app name, the AppID and app type (e.g. Android, Web, IOs) as identifiers for each app. Unfortunately there is no description of what the app does or link to further info on the purpose of the app. In addition the app names are not unique.

**Problem;**
I have over 5,000 apps to look into for internal 3rd party review/security purposes. I need to find any way to get more information on each specific app (such as a description of what the app does or a link to a webpage with more info) when the only unique identifier I have to work with is the App ID.

**Tried so far;**
I have looked through MANY MANY google APIs and SDKs but have had no luck finding anything that will accept an app ID and return more information on the details of the app (unless I own the app, which I don't). I have also contacted GSuite admin support but unfortunately their suggestion was to pay someone for the service. I find it hard to believe there is no way to use the app ID to look up an app (that you don't own) for more info.

**Current (terrible) approach;**
At this point I'm facing a manual approach!!! I.e. having to paste the app ID into google and hope for some search results that point to something of use. For over 5,000 apps this is less than ideal and I have serious concerns about the  reliability of such results.

Some example app ids (with the same name) are;

- 1032199425885-oq9scukspijc682n7k2erv386nc58que.apps.googleusercontent.com
- 1032199425885-u2he6guukdl2g7n0vhpqmsn5qpips02k.apps.googleusercontent.com
- 1032199425885-ub6hlugo3efflq7ppdbccfnuto17d804.apps.googleusercontent.com

**SOS**
Is anyone aware of an API/SDK/code/script that can be **reliably** used to lookup an app based on it's app ID, where the type can be either "iOS", "Web Application" or "Android"? Any suggestions anyone can make would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is one API [Resource manager api](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/) its extremely limited last i checked this is all it returned

```
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "projectNumber": "xxxxx",
      "projectId": "api-project-1xxxx",
      "lifecycleState": "ACTIVE",
      "name": "Android Real-Time Analytics",
      "createTime": "2013-10-02T19:21:14.161Z"
    },
    {
      "projectNumber": "xxxxxx",
      "projectId": "googleanalytics",
      "lifecycleState": "ACTIVE",
      "name": "API Project",
      "createTime": "2012-09-14T08:07:06.906Z"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably either found a solution by then or gave up, but I went in the same issue and found a workaround that could help others with the same need.

First part of what you refer to as App ID (before the "-") is actually the App ID.
I guess the second part refers to a version ID...

I have not found a way to query Google Workspace Marketplace with that ID directly, but Google dorks help :).
Simply use "inurl: site:workspace.google.com" in Google Search and voilà!

For instance, "inurl:1032199425885 site:workspace.google.com" returns "https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/asana/1032199425885" as first result